# What is the meaning of $\langle f'(x), y-x \rangle$ in Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: notation

In Lipschitz continuous, there is a Theorem that

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous gradient on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have

$$|f(y) - f(x) - \langle f'(x),y-x\rangle| \leq  \frac{L}{2} \lVert y-x \rVert ^2$$

I would ask what is the meaning of $\langle f'(x),y-x\rangle$.

Comment: I think you meant to ask this on [math.SE] This site is for users of Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: It means that `Grad[f[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}] . ({y1, y2, y3} - {x1, x2, x3})` for n=3;

Comment: Quite often one uses the notation $\langle a, b \rangle$ to denote the inner product of two variables $a$ and $b$. I believe here then tnat $\langle f^\prime(x), y - x\rangle$ is the inner product of $f^\prime(x)$ and $ y - x$.

Comment: The intended meaning is that this is the dot product of the gradient of $f$ at $x$ with the vector $y - x$.